# how to put the words in the text file into dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to put all the words in the txt file into a dictionary:

For example, I have the f.txt like this:

> ```
> a tom
> a sam
> b stern 
> c stern 
> a king
> ```

I expect to get:

```
{'a': 'tom', 'sam', 'king', 'b':'stern', 'c': 'stern'}
```

Here's my code

```
new_dict = {}
myFile = open('f.txt', 'r')
for line in myFile:
    line2=line.split()
    group=line2[0]
    name=line2[1]
    new_dict[group]= name
new_dict
```

There is an issue with this code. The output does not read this file well, I only get part of the keys and values, not all of them.

for example:

I got this:

```
{'a': 'tom', 'b':'stern'}
```

How to deal with this?

Comment: That thing you expect to get isn't a valid `dict`. Did you want the multiple values to go into a list, like this? `{'a': ['tom', 'sam', 'king'], 'b':'stern', 'c': 'stern'} `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot associate multiple values with one key like that. You should use tuples or lists.
With your current code you end up over-writing the last list item you added to the dictionary. Instead, try

```
for line in myFile:
    line2 = line.split()
    group = line2[0]
    name = line2[1]
    if group in new_dict: 
        new_dict[group].append(name)
    else: # Create new list if it doesn't exist
        new_dict[group] = [name]
print new_dict
```

That would give you an output of

```
{'a': ['tom', 'sam', 'king'], 'b':['stern'], 'c': ['stern']}
```

Comment: Do you need `import` any library to do this? except `pandas` to read the txt

Comment: @NabihIbrahimBawazir No you don't need to import anything for this part of the code. You can also read the file without `pandas`.

Comment: Thanks @Antimony, your answer is helpful!

Comment: @Antimony also, I have a follow up question: i would like to print my dictionary in this way: a: tom, sam, king n/ b: stern n/ c: stern. Do you know any way to print like this?

Comment: You could iterate over each key and print each of the corresponding list items. However, dictionaries do not maintain keys in any particular order, so you may not be able to print in that order: a, b, c ... You could sort the keys first (`sorted(new_dict.keys()`) and then access their values in order though.